# Inverse limit in category of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, category-theory, geometric-topology

Let $... \leftarrow G_i \leftarrow G_{i+1} \leftarrow ...$ be an inverse system of graphs (which might not  be locally finite), morphisms are symplicial maps (we allow collapsing of edges to vertices).

We define a combinatorial inverse limit as follows: 
-vertices are sequences ${x_i}$ such that each $x_i$ is a vertex for $G_i$, 
-vertices ${x_i}$ and ${y_i}$ are connected iff for every $i$ we have: $x_i$ and $y_i$ are equal or are connected in $G_i$.

As a set, a combinatorial inverse limit is same as the standard inverse limit of topological spaces, but the topology is different.
In particular, a combinatorial inverse limit of connected graphs might be disconnected.

This construction seems very natural and I wonder if there is anything known about that?

I want to study how Gromov's hyperbolicity behaves when one passes to the inverse limit.
The main example is the inverse limit of graphs of homotopy classes of curves on a surface.

Comment: This and other constructions are described in detail in the book "Profinite graphs and groups" by Luis Ribes.